# Badge Benefactor: how to be awarded by one's own bounty?

Tags: support, badges, bounty

I'm looking into the Badge `Benefactor`:

First bounty you manually awarded on your own question

So I'm wondering: if one cannot get the bounty for himself/herself, how can this happen?

---

For more, I see four badges about bounty, what's the difference? I'm a bit amazed, please tell.

1. Altruist: First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
2. Benefactor: First bounty you manually awarded on your own question
3. Investor: First bounty you offered on another person's question
4. Promoter: First bounty you offered on your own question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You earn the badge by awarding a bounty to an answer on your own question; both the *question* and the *bounty you set on it* are your own, but not the answer.

See the [central badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399):

> #### Benefactor
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Award a bounty on your own question
>
>   - Awarding means manually selecting a bounty winner; letting the system auto-award half the bounty does not count
>       ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67957))
> - Not awarded on per-site metas, since those sites do not have bounties

Each of the 4 *bounty* badges teach you about *starting* and *awarding* bounties; two each for bounties on your own and on someone else's question.

Comment: I'm amazed about the four badges about bounty, what's the difference? I don't quite catch the meaning.

Comment: @fish_ball: they teach you about *starting* and *awarding* a bounty, both on your own question and on someone else's question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not for receiving the bounty. That badge is awarded for you creating a bounty on your own question and then actually giving it to someone, rather than letting Community auto-award it or letting it expire.

Comment: I'm amazed about the four badges about bounty, what's the difference? I don't quite catch the meaning.

Comment: One badge is for creating a bounty on your own question, and one is for creating a bounty on someone else's question. Similarly, one is for awarding said bounty to someone on your own question, and the other is for awarding said bounty on someone else's question.